# ruby set a = b, perform operation on b, but a changes value too

Tags: ruby

I am seeing some weird behavior (or maybe I just don't understand it).

When I run the following code

```
a = [[1,2],[3,4]]
b = a
b.each do |r|
  r[0] = r[0] + 1
end
```

the values for both a and b have changed. Why is this? Also, how does one make it so that there is a copy of the original array as well as one of the new array? Thanks

Comment: It's because `b = a` makes b and a both point to the same object. If you want them to be different objects but identical, you need to make what's called a "deep copy."

Comment: so how do I store another copy of a so that i can have both the original array and the new array?

Comment: You can do `b = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(a))` in this particular case as a quick and dirty workaround for ruby's lack of a "proper" deep copy operation.

Comment: @scott_fakename, `Marshal`'s not needed for two-dimensional arrays. `b.map { |r0,r1| [r0+1,r1] }` is enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Mutable Objects with Same Object ID

When you say `b = a` you are assigning the same mutable object to two variables. Consider the following:

```
a = [[1,2],[3,4]]
b = a
a.object_id == b.object_id
#=> true
```

Since both variables point to the same mutable object, making changes to the object stored by either variable changes the underlying object. Now consider the same operation with the [Enumerator#dup](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-dup) method inherited by the [Array](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html) class:

```
a = [[1,2],[3,4]]
b = a.dup
a.object_id == b.object_id
#=> false
```

Comment: `b.each {|r| r[0] = r[0] + 1}` would still affect array `a`.

Comment: @steenslag `b = a.dup; b.pop; pp a, b`. The problem isn't #dup, the problem is that if you modify the stored object held in the array, rather than the array itself, you still get the behavior. But this is ultimately a self-inflicted wound from legal (but improper) assignment.

Answer (score 2):

Because `b` and `a` point to the same object, which in turn means that their elements are the same objects.

To make a copy, use `dup`. To make a deep copy, apply `dup` to the elements as well.

Answer (score 0):

That behavior is not weird, when you do "b = a" this simply means that now b points to the same object as a. a changes the value because it's the same memory location.

Answer (score 0):

You can understand it by "object_id" method.

> **object_id**: Returns an integer identifier for obj.

```
2.1.2 :101 > a= [[1,2],[3,4]]
 => [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
2.1.2 :102 > a.object_id
 => 70360382470860
2.1.2 :103 > b = a
 => [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
2.1.2 :104 > b.object_id
 => 70360382470860
2.1.2 :105 >
```

You can use "b = a.clone"